# testing for background color in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Just a note: I am not very versed in coding and brand new to google script.

I am trying test for background color within a script.  Specifically, I will have an array of names stored into a named range and want to count how many cells are set to green.
So far I have the following but receive an error: TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "#00ff00"

```
function testCount(range) {

  var ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("testrange");
  var names = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("testrange").getValues();

  var NumColumns = ranges.getNumColumns();
  var NumRows = ranges.getNumRows();
  var c = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i<NumColumns; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j<NumRows; j++){
      if (ranges.getBackgrounds()[i][j] ="#00ff00"){ 
        c++;
      }else{
        c=c;
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
```

I grabbed the value for green when I tried the following for a cell that was colored

```
return ranges.getBackgrounds()[0][1];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just looks like your code needs a little cleaning. I'll explain the edits.

```
function testCount() {

  var ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("testrange");
```

No need to have the `var names` line because it seems that you don't use it.

```
  var NumColumns = ranges.getNumColumns();
  var NumRows = ranges.getNumRows();
```

Grab the backgrounds of all the cells at once and store that in a variable.

```
  var backgrounds = ranges.getBackgrounds();
  var c = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i<NumColumns; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j<NumRows; j++){
```

Reference the `backgrounds` variable that we created above. Also, the first number is the row number, and the second number is the column number. So you'll want to swap `i` and `j` from what you had originally. Also, `a = 10` *assigns* the value of 10 to the variable a. To check for equality, you use `==`. This checks if the two values are the same.

```
      if (backgrounds[j][i] == "#00ff00"){ 
        c++;
      }
```

No need to have an `else` statement that doesn't do anything. You can leave the `else` part out.

```
    }
  }
  return c;
}
```

Comment: sorry Phil, almost in synch ;-)

Comment: does it really need explanation ? I find it quite easy to understand how it works. But anyway I can remove it if you want, no worries...

Comment: @Sergeinsas, I was just making a joke. You didn't have to take down your answer. Your answer was a good one.

Comment: ;-) it was word for word the same code, no need for duplicates... and your answer was indeed better commented ! (just one detail : you should remove the argument in the function name `testCount(range)`, you probably forgot it...and it is useless here)

Comment: Also : you iterate from 0 to numColumns, I think it should be numColumns-1 since arrays are 0 indexed an numColumns counts from 1.(same for rows). That why I used `backgrounds.length` and `backgrounds[0].length` instead...

Comment: `backgrounds.length` is the same thing as `NumRows`. The for loop continues while `i` is less than `NumRows`, so it stops at `NumRows-1`. Thanks for the suggestions though!