# Counting based on the color of two adjacent cells in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm new to Javascript and am trying to create a script in Google Spreadsheets that can look at a row for cells with this color #6d9eeb and check if the cell directly below cells with that color has this color #d9ead3. If so it will increment a counter. I then want this action repeated every 6 rows (Starting with row 11).

So far the most I've managed to do is write a script that can tell me the colors of different cells.

```
function testColor()
{

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");

var cellColor = cell.getBackground();

var test = Logger.log(cellColor)

};
```

Comment: Welcome. did you read [testing for background color in google script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181333/1330560) when you did your research. This covers a fair bit of your question.

Comment: Does the post on "Testing for a background color" help out? I notice that your code didn't include an attempt at looping (which is necessary for running though the rows &/or columns. The looping in this situation is a bit more complicated than usual - do you need help with that?